# The address of the last byte of the second pointer

Tags: c++

I need to write a code that prints the address of the last byte of the second pointer.
I tried to do this via GPT, but I can't explain why pointer type conversions are needed here.
Help explain this.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int q = 10;
    
    int *pq = &q,
      **ppq = &pq;
    
    char* lastByte = (char*)(ppq) + sizeof(ppq) - 1;
    
    std::cout << ppq << std::endl;
    std::cout << (void*)lastByte << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

0x7ff7bfeff150
0x7ff7bfeff157

I tried this, but the answer is not correct.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int q = 10;
    
    int *pq = &q,
      **ppq = &pq;
    
    std::cout << ppq << std::endl;
    std::cout << ppq + sizeof(ppq) - 1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

0x7ff7bfeff150
0x7ff7bfeff188

Comment: *"I need to write a code that..." Why?* I don't see any reason to do this. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The first conversion `(char*)` is required so that the *pointer arithmetic* uses bytes not ints. The second conversion `(void*)` is required so that C++ does not try to print your pointer as if it pointed to a null terminated string (which is the standard way of printing `char*`).

Comment: What is the 'last byte of the second pointer'? Now I'm looking closer at your code that's not clear at all.

Comment: I can understand why you have `pq` but the reason for the `ppq` variable is not obvious.

Comment: This should only be taught in datastructures class, with the explicit warning : you have to do this now, but stay away from pointer arithmetic in C++ forever after! Tell this to your teacher too (also tell him to read this : https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines)

Comment: sizeof(ppq) - 1 = 7, so it is 0x7ff7bfeff150 + 7 * size of ppq element = 0x7ff7bfeff150 + 7 * 8 = 0x7ff7bfeff188.  That char* cast makes the ppq element size 1 instead of 8.  In practice the exercise is much simpler, on a little-endian architecture the last byte of a pointer is at the little end, so simply &q.

Comment: In (char*)(ppq) the parentheses around ppq are nonsense. They are either unneeded or have no effect.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic works in terms of size of the pointee.    So, for example, if an `int *` points at the first element of an array of `int`, incrementing gives a pointer to the second element - even if (as is usually the case in practice) `sizeof(int)` is not equal to `1`.   You're incorrectly assuming pointer arithmetic works in bytes.   The conversions in the first code sample are necessary to count in `char`s` (for which `sizeof` always gives `1`, by definition in the standard)

Comment: I don't thin that GPT understood what you wanted. Humans are failing to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the address of last byte of `ppq`, you can do:

```
    std::cout << static_cast<void *>( &(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&ppq))[sizeof(ppq) - 1] ) << std::endl;
```

---

For better understanding:

```
    unsigned char * p_ppq = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&ppq);

    std::cout << static_cast<void *>(&p_ppq[sizeof(ppq) - 1]) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Who even writes code like that? Regardless,

```
  int **ppq = &pq
  ppq + sizeof(ppq)
```

ppq is a pointer to a pointer. Pointer arithmetic works like it does for arrays -- if "x" is a pointer to int, and you have 4 byte ints, then x+1 advances the pointer by 4 so it points to the next int, not just to the next memory address.

After all, you'd expect x[1] to give you the next integer as well, not just some random garbage made from 3 bytes of the first integer and 1 byte from the second integer on the data chunk. C-style arrays and pointers are pretty much the same thing, so this applies to pointers as well.

A pointer generally has 8 bytes on a 64 bit platform, so your ppq+sizeof() actually advances the pointer "8 pointers ahead", or 8*8 bytes. Then your -1 takes it 1 pointer (aka 8 bytes) back -- so you're advancing by 56 bytes, or 0x38 bytes.